# Xamarin Android light sensor - get current value

Tags: android, xamarin, sensors

My question is how can I immediately get values for Light Sensor in Android Xamarin, or any other sensor for that matter.

So far I only found how to register changes that come from those sensors through listeners. But how do I get initial value? In case if no significant change in light levels happens, how can I force OnSensorChanged event to fire, or where do I look for values in the Sensor itself?

Answer (score 2):

Check this post: https://programmium.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/retrieve-data-from-light-sensor-with-xamarin-android

Let me know :)

Comment: Thank you very much for replying :) I have already seen this post, it doesn't show how to extract current light value from sensor, it only shows how to record if this value changes.

Comment: @user2252487, are you using a SensorManager?